# Inclusion-exclusion principle problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I currently faced a problem I couldn't solve: given sets A, B and C, s.t. $|A \setminus B|=24,|B \setminus C|=17, |C \setminus A|=11, |A \cap B \cap C|=11$ find the cardinality of $A\cup B\cup C$.

What I tried is $|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C| + |A\cap B \cap C|$ but I'm stuck here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try to draw a Venn diagram and find the numbers in each sub-region and add them up.

Comment: How do I find the intersections though?

Comment: My fault, you don't need to find each sub-region.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Rewrite

$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|A\cap B|-|A\cap C|-|B\cap C| + |A\cap B \cap C|$

As

$|A\cup B\cup C|=|A|-|A\cap B| +|B|-|B\cap C| + |C| - |A\cap C|+ |A\cap B \cap C|$

Now $|A| - |A \cap B| = |A \setminus B|$. Similarly check other pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$$|A\setminus B| +  |B\setminus C| + |C\setminus A| = ?$$

Answer (score 0):

By drawing a Venn diagram this can be solved. You will find that all you need to do is add the numbers.

Note that $|A\backslash B|$ denoted the number of elements in $A$ **without** $B$ and so that includes all the elements in $|A|$ except $|A\cap B|$. Therefore $|A\backslash B|=|A|-|A\cap B|$

Similarly, $|B\backslash C|=|B|-|B\cap C|$ and $|C\backslash A|=|C|-|C\cap A|$

Replace these in your formula and so you only need to add the numbers and the final answer would be $63$.